# Should I get heavy data for object when needed or carry as properties?

Tags: objective-c, object, mapkit, shapefile, esri

I'm working on a project that uses the Shapefile C Library (http://shapelib.maptools.org) to draw map overlays via MapKit.  I have an object that at the moment is carrying around the polygonal and coordinate data for the geographic component that it comprises.  My high level conceptual question is this: am I better off keeping the object simple and creating a method that for instance would call shapeDataForShapeWithName:(NSString *)name which would fetch the shape data from the database when needed, or take the approach i've taken: call the DB upon Object instantiation and store each instances data to instance variables?

Thanks!

Comment: From what perspective of being 'better off'?

Comment: Mostly efficiency.  Ease of implementation drove me towards my current method, but I fear it's hurting performance.

Comment: When you measure it in Instruments, how big of an impact is it having?